# Keras-rl ValueError"Model has more than one output. DQN expects a model that has a single output"

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, dqn, keras-rl

Is there any way to get around this error? I have a model with a 15x15 input grid, which leads to two outputs. Each output has 15 possible values, which are x or y coordinates. I did this because it is significantly simpler than having 225 separate outputs for every location on the grid.
The problem is that when i try to train the model using this code:

```
def build_agent(model,actions)
  policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
  memory = SequentialMemory(limit=100000, window_length=1)
  dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory,policy=policy,nb_actions=actions,nb_steps_warmup=100, target_model_update=1e-2)
  return(dqn)
dqn = build_agent(model, np.array([15,15]))
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate = 0.01), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=10000, action_repetition=1, visualize=False, verbose=1,nb_max_episode_steps=10000)
plt.show()
```

I get the error: "Model has more than one output. DQN expects a model that has a single output".
The model summary is below so you can see there are 2 output layers.

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1, 15, 15)]  0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)              (None, 12, 13, 13)   120         ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 11, 3)    354         ['conv2d_2[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 flatten_1 (Flatten)            (None, 330)          0           ['conv2d_3[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)            (None, 330)          0           ['flatten_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 15)           4965        ['dropout_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 15)           4965        ['dropout_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 10,404
Trainable params: 10,404
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Standard Keras allows a model with multiple outputs using the functional api but from the errpr message i assume that feature is just not supported for Keras-rl? If thats true, is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: It is not that its not supported, the DQN algorithm requires a model with a single output, what exactly do you expect DQN to do with the extra outputs?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy As i said in my post, the extra output would be useful as it would cut the number of outputs from 225 to 30, x and y coordinate instead of a single value. I know this is possible with a standard ANN so i dont understand why a DQN algorithm (which as i understand is essentially a standard ANN which learns by interacting with the environment instead of through the backpropagation algorithm) would find this impossible?

Comment: No, you misunderstand how DQN works, you might be surprised to now learn that DQN also uses backpropagation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Well i mean is it incorrect that a standard NN has a set of inputs and correct outputs, then uses backpropagation to adjust weights and biases to increase accuracy, but a DQN does a similar thing except explores the environment and determines the value of action by looking at the results, then uses backpropagation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that i had to just use one output of 225. This didn't work great, but it was the best i could find. Two different outputs will not work using keras-rl, so this was all i could think of. Another possibility would be using a different library such as stable baselines2, but that would be completely different to the already built code.